# ListView with Sections Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, expandablelistview

How do I program my adapter in order to visualize the contents of an `ArrayList` in a `onPostExecute` inside an `AsynkTask`?

I have got the following class:

```
class PlatoCuenta{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public Integer served_as;
    public String served;
    public String price;
    public String quantity;
    public String title_cuenta;
}
```

I have got the following array list:

```
ArrayList<PlatoCuenta> bebidas=new ArrayList<PlatoCuenta>();

bebidas=new ArrayList<PlatoCuenta>();

JSONArray mArray = new JSONArray(jsonstr);
for(int i = 0; i < mArray.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject currentObject = mArray.getJSONObject(i);

    PlatoCuenta producto= new PlatoCuenta();
    SectionItem SectionCuenta = new SectionItem();
    producto.id=currentObject.getString("id");
    producto.served=currentObject.getString("served");

    if(currentObject.getString("price").equals("None")) 
        producto.price="0.00";
    else
        producto.price=currentObject.getString("price");

    producto.name= currentObject.getString("product_name");
    producto.quantity=currentObject.getString("product_number");
    producto.served_as = currentObject.getInt("serv_order");

    if(producto.served_as==0){
        SectionCuenta.title="bebidas";
        producto.title_cuenta=SectionCuenta.title;
        bebidas.add(producto);
    }
    if(producto.served_as==2){
        SectionCuenta.title="entrantes";
        producto.title_cuenta=SectionCuenta.title;
        bebidas.add(producto);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you create adapter class?

Comment: fixed formatting, clarified question

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have `ArrayList<PlatoCuenta> bebidas=new ArrayList<PlatoCuenta>();`. The general steps for visualize a listview are:

1. Create a row layout row.xml
2. Create an adapter for the row
3. Set adapter to the listview.

Again, suppose that you already have the design of your row.xml. To create an adapter (step 2).

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    //....
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row.xml, parent, false);
   //continue creating your row here

 return rowView;
 }
}
```

And in `onPostExecute`:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context,bebidas);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Good tutorial: [Custom ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)